# Google Play Publish Supported devices 0

Tags: android, google-play, live-wallpaper

I developed an app which works on my phone using AndEngine 1.0 and it is a live wallpaper.

Having just uploaded my app to the Play store I get: **Supported devices 0** . The app is activated and here is my manifest:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="some.package"
              android:versionCode="4"
              android:versionName="1.0">

        <uses-sdk
                android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15"
                />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.software.live_wallpaper"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone" android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.sensor" android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb" android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi" android:required="false" />
        <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type" android:required="false" />

        <application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">

            <service
                    android:name="my.package.Main"
                    android:enabled="true"
                    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                    android:label="@string/app_name"
                    android:permission="android.permission.BIND_WALLPAPER">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.service.wallpaper.WallpaperService"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data
                        android:name="android.service.wallpaper"
                        android:resource="@xml/wallpaper"/>
            </service>


        </application>

    </manifest>
```

And the output of aapt:

```
    package: name='some.package' versionCode='4' versionName='1.0'
    sdkVersion:'15'
    targetSdkVersion:'15'
    uses-feature:'android.software.live_wallpaper'
    uses-permission:'android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE'
    uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.camera'
    uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.camera.autofocus'
    uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.location'
    uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.location.gps'
    uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.location.network'
    uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.microphone'
    uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.telephony'
    uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.touchscreen'
    uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.sensor'
    uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.usb'
    uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.wifi'
    uses-feature-not-required:'android.hardware.type'
    application-icon-160:'res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png'
    application-icon-240:'res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png'
    application-icon-320:'res/drawable-xhdpi/ic_launcher.png'
    application: label='' icon='res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png'
    wallpaper
    supports-screens: 'small' 'normal' 'large' 'xlarge'
    supports-any-density: 'true'
    locales: '--_--'
    densities: '160' '240' '320'
    native-code: 'armebi'
```

in my libs/ folder I have andengine-o.jar, android-support.jar, commons-math.jar. The whole thing is built using proguard.

What could be causing this issue?

(I've followed advice on other posts on sof such as setting user-features to false)

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I had a native library armebi with a .so file in my libs folder, once I removed it the number of devices shot up > 0.